# Windows 8 Phone how to close popup when user clicks anywhere

Tags: windows-phone-8

noob here.  I created a simple windows 8 phone app using C# and xaml and when the user "wins" a popup comes up on the screen saying "you win, tap anywhere to continue".  When the user clicks anywhere (on the popup or outside of it) the popup should close.  I can't figure out how to get the popup to close.

my xaml looks like this:

```
<Popup  x:Name="pu" IsOpen="False" >
```

my c# like this:

```
if (user wins the game)
    pu.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: The problem you will run into, with any type of silverlight app, is that inside the popup and outside the popup are handled differently. They are different UI elements. The best way to do what you're asking is to display a almost transparent (this is important) rectangle behind your popup that covers the whole screen. Then handle the tap event for that rectangle and the tap event for your popup the same

Comment: cool beans, this is basically what I've done, and it works so far.  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done in two places

1. The dialog which handles the mouse click event will subscribe to it and close it within its border (normal).
2. The window behind (below) it will also subscribe to the mouse click event and if the popup is open, it will close it.

Answer (score 0):

By including this(IsLightDismissEnabled="True") property into your pop up element will close the pop up when the user clicks anywhere (on the popup or outside of it).